# java heap dump shows less retained heap memory than expected

Tags: java

I am checking the heap dump of my application. The application has a `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap` where Key type is `java.lang.String` and value is a User defined Class with a `byte[]` field.

I have added 16000 keys with 30 characters each, and the value's byte array is 3000 bytes. So i expect overall retained heap size of concurrent hashmap to be 48MB (16000 * 3000).

But the value in heap dump is 24MB. When i check further, i find there are many entries like below. these entries have HashMap Node's retained size is far less than the sum of retained size of key and value.

How to understand this discrepancy?

```
Class Name                                                                             | Shallow Heap | Retained Heap
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[5490] java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node @ 0x6c6a23910                       |           32 |           136
|- <class> class java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node @ 0x6c71bc320 System Class|            0 |             0
|- key java.lang.String @ 0x6c6a23930  /data-node-3-10/parent2/child2                  |           24 |           104
|- val org.apache.zookeeper.server.DataNode @ 0x6c6a23998                              |           32 |         3,304
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

PS: My task at hand is to find a correlation between system configuration and memory usage.

**EDIT**: for many other entries the values are as below. The retained size of the HashMap Node (3160) contains retained size of Node's key(128) + value(3000).
But for some entries (e.g. as shown above) it doesn't seem to be correct(136) for a node with key and value 's retained size is 104 and 3304 respectively.

```
Class Name                                                                             | Shallow Heap | Retained Heap
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[9706] java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node @ 0x6c6a1ab98                       |           32 |         3,160
|- <class> class java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node @ 0x6c71bc320 System Class|            0 |             0
|- key java.lang.String @ 0x6c6a1abb8  /data-node-0-10/parent1/child2/grandchild1      |           24 |           128
|- val org.apache.zookeeper.server.DataNode @ 0x6c6a1ac38                              |           32 |         3,000
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Without code, especially for your data class, we have no way of guessing. I suspect that since this is a *managed* environment, not just a free-for-all regular JVM application, that deduplication may be going on. Alternately, depending on where you got that report (you didn't say, and you didn't provide units), it may be counting only the cost of the map entries *themselves* and not the downstream references.

Comment: it is actually Zookeeper. i am running a 3 member ensemble. and took heap dump for one of the members after creating 16000 entries. Since the value is a `byte[]` perhaps de duplication is not happening? and all keys are unique anyway.